# Element PaddingRight Value

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding, getelementbyid

I have troubles with a short scripts, which doesn't work.
It will change the paddingRight value of an element in my website.

```
var sidebarElm = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    if(sidebarElm == null){
        document.getElementById("container").style.paddingRight = "0px";
    }
    else{
        var sidebarwidth = document.getElementById("sidebar").offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById("container").style.paddingRight = sidebarwidth + "px";
    }
```

Thank you !

EDIT : I use CodeIgniter for my website.

EDIT 2 : RESOLVED !
In fact, I just had to load the script at the end; not in the head section.
So I place it in the footer section and that works fine ! Thank you all :)

Comment: "troubles" = ? Please be specific.

Comment: Use this and adapt to your code and post back: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3bqj/

Comment: I also made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/z2LLB/. It shows the difference between your two cases, one with no padding and one with padding equal to the sidebar width. What's the problem?

Comment: The error is obviously in the HTML. I guess that sidebar has a width of 0.

Comment: Here is what I'm looking for, unfortunately it doesn't work on my website. http://jsfiddle.net/Q3bqj/1/

Comment: Well, does your site have more CSS, that can interfere with the workings of the script? Is the script called at all, and at the right moment (i.e. not before the whole DOM tree is generated)?

Comment: Thank you Mr Lister, it was indeed the script which was loaded too early ! Thank you.